# Change variable inside react exported function in another file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, frontend

I'm helping build a website using react and typescript, which i'm very new to, and i'm trying to access handlePath inside the function that i'm exporting in another file to alter the variable homePath on the click of a button. I'm gonna abstract the reason to why i need to do this to save time but basically, this is what i'm doing which is not working :(

```
file1.tsx:

export default function Func1(): JSX.Element {

    const [homePath, setHomePath] = useState(0);

    const handlePath = () => setHomePath(1);

return (
    homePath ? 
        //doing something
)};

file2.tsx:

import Func1 form "./file1";

Export default funtion Func2(): JSX.Element {

    ...

    return (
        
        <Button data-testid="botaoCadastro" onClick={handlePath} to="/Cadastro" shadow>
            Button
        </Button>

)};
```

Comment: What is the relation of these two components?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to create something that React calls a (custom) hook. Refer to the following article https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html